# Offer similar tags when dialog to create new tag opens

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation

I think it will be a lot more useful if the prompt on new tag creation shows similarly sound alternatives whenever a user attempts to create a new tag.

Comment: What do you mean "similarly sound"? You mean as in vocal? That would be terribly complex to implement and not worth the effort. Anyway it's crucial to know so please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: It's not. All major databases have "sounds like" and fuzzy search for a decade at least. Lense - lenses for example

Comment: So on cooking if rigatoni didn't exist it might suggest ministrone because it sounds similar? Is anyone likely to find that a useful suggestion?

Comment: @RobertLongson when I'm hungry I take any suggestion.

Comment: Can you clarify the intended meaning of "sound"? For example, it [could be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sound#Adjective) as in *"2. Complete, solid, or secure."* /  *"4. Good; acceptable; decent."* /  *"1. Healthy."*. [Or](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sound#Verb): "2. To convey an impression by one's sound." (example: *"That story sounds like a pack of lies!"*).